# Append text length in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to append the length of the value of a text field to a label, it actually does append, but for each value it appends a new length(not replacing the old length).

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<script type="text/javascript"
      src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js">
    </script>
<body>
<input type="text" id="text-box" value="" />
<button id="me">click</button>
<label id="len-val"></label>
<script>
$("#text-box").keydown(function(){

var lent = $(this).val().length;

var bosk = $("#len-val");

 bosk.append(lent);

});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: use `.text()` or `.html()` rather than `.append()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `.text()` instead of `append()`

```
bosk.text(lent);
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/3w43kfna/)

**Update**

@Shin posted a comment *Enter some value,Select all,press delete,Not set to 0*

To fix this you must use `.keyup()`

```
$("#text-box").keyup(function () {
    var lent = $(this).val().length;
    var bosk = $("#len-val");
    bosk.text(lent);
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/3w43kfna/1/)

Comment: Enter some value,Select all,press delete,Not set to 0 :)

Comment: @Shin Updated, the problem is that the event was keydown.

Comment: @Shin Ah i just saw you answered that 36 min ago, sry +1 to you.

Comment: Enter some value,select all,right click,delete, I am looking for a solution for that +1

Comment: @Shin I think `.change()` would be the best possible solution for that

Answer (score 2):

Problem is that you are using `.append()` which is appending you need to use `.text()`

Use

```
bosk.text(lent); //It will overwrite existing text
```

instead of

```
bosk.append(lent);
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/31z6u71u/)

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#text-box").keyup(function(){
 var lent = $(this).val().length;
 var bosk = $("#len-val");
 bosk.html(lent);
});
```

**[FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Ljgwtdpx/)**

Answer (score 0):

use [`text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) or [`html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) instead of  [`append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append/) as follows:

```
bosk.text(lent); // or bosk.html(lent);
```